# How Multiple persons can work on the Same Magento project

Tags: magento

I have an issue such that mutiple persons need to work on magneto files, mostly style.css file and layouts ect. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: This question appears to be "how do I do version/source control", and as such is likely off topic (too broad)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not really a "development" issue, but you should use something like git or svn.

Comment: Even if it's a single developer, learn how to use a version management system like git. It allows quick branching when you have to do patches, etc. and allows for quick backout when a major change kills your ecommerce website despite having proved out in development, providing you do database backups before committing those changes.

Comment: Of course yes, it's a very useful tool. And it's even more justified if they are more than one.